# Wie nennt man in Deutschland die »Stiege« als Bestandteil einer Adresse?

Tags: meaning, regional

Wenn in Österreich eine Wohnhausanlage über mehrere Eingänge verfügt (das ist hauptsächlich in Städten der Fall), dann sind diese Eingänge durchnummeriert, und eine solche Nummer ist Bestandteil der Adresse einer Wohnung, die über diesen Eingang erreichbar ist. Ich gehe mal davon aus, dass das auch in Deutschland der Fall ist.

Dieser Adress-Bestandteil, der zwischen Hausnummer und Türnummer steht, heißt in Österreich »Stiege«, wie im folgenden Formular unter Punkt 3.4 zu sehen ist:

[image: österreichisches Formular]

Nun habe ich heute aber erfahren, dass das Wort »Stiege« in diesem Sinn nur in Österreich verwendet wird. Allerdings habe ich nicht erfahren, wie man stattdessen in Deutschland zu dieser Nummer sagt. Der Begriff, der mir als potenzielle deutschländische Alternative in den Sinn kommt, ist »Treppe«, allerdings ist das nur ins Blaue geraten, und ich würde es gerne genauer wissen.

---

Konkret sind die beiden Begriffe in Österreich mit folgenden Bedeutungen belegt:

- **Treppe**
  Eine Treppe besteht aus drei oder mehr Stufen und verbindet ein Stockwerk mit einem unmittelbar darüber oder darunter liegenden anderen Stockwerk. Sie kann auch geringere Höhen überwinden, z.B. wenn unterschiedliche Niveaus innerhalb eines Gebäudes oder im Freien überwunden werden.

Wenn man aber beispielsweise vom 3. in das 5. Stockwerk geht, denn geht man über zwei Treppen. Von dieser Einschränkung sind nur Wendeltreppen ausgenommen, die auch mehrere Stockwerke miteinander verbinden können.

- **Stiege**
  Dieses Wort hat mehrere Bedeutungen (diverse Maßeinheiten, Bezeichnung für Behälter u.a.). Im Zusammenhang mit meiner Fragestellung sind aber nur diese drei relevant:

1. Synonym für »Treppe«, im Wesentlichen ganz wie oben beschrieben, jedoch mit dem Unterschied, dass eine Stiege in jedem Fall auch mehrere Stockwerke verbinden kann. Alle Treppen, die hintereinander angeordnet sind, um vom untersten Kellergeschoß bis zum Dachboden zu gelangen, bilden zusammen eine Stiege. Die Stiege selbst besteht dabei nur aus den einzelnen Treppen und den Plateaus, welche diese Treppen miteinander verbinden. Will man auch die Wände, die die Stiege umgeben, in einem Begriff zusammen mit der eigentlichen Stiege nennen, dann spricht man von einem »*Stiegenhaus*«.
   (Eine Wendeltreppe ist aber auch in Österreich eine Wendel*treppe* und keine Wendel*stiege*.)
2. Alle Wohneinheiten in einer Wohnhausanlage, deren Wohnungstüren von demselben Stiegenhaus aus erreichbar sind.
3. Die Ordnungsnummer einer Stiege (siehe Bedeutung 2). Diese Nummer ist ein amtlicher Bestandteil einer Postanschrift (Adresse).

Meine Frage dreht sich um die Bedeutung 3 von »Stiege«: Wie wird dieser Bestandteil einer Postanschrift in Deutschland genannt?

Mich würden auch andere Abweichungen von den von mir geschilderten Bedeutungen interessieren.

[image: Stiege]

---

### Nachtrag

(Reaktion auf die bisherigen Antworten)

Vielleicht ist das System der Nummernvergabe in Deutschland tatsächlich anders als in Österreich. Um aber Missverständnisse auszuräumen, möchte ich versuchen klarer zu machen, worum es mir geht.

Es geht nicht um Reihenhäuser am Rand einer Kleinstadt, die mit Waldweg 6, 6a, 6b, 6c usw. durchnummeriert sind. Das sind ja getrennte Häuser, auch wenn sie möglicherweise Wand an Wand stehen.

Ich meine große Wohnhausanlagen, wie man sie in den dicht besiedelten Wohngegenden von mittleren und großen Städten findet. Ich habe beispielsweise eine Zeit lang im [Wiener Gasometer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasometer_(Wien)) gewohnt. Das war früher ein Gasspeicher, ist aber seit 2001 eine Wohnhausanlage samt Shoppingmall. Jeder der vier Türme hat eine Hausnummer (Guglgasse 6, 8, 12 und 14; auf Nummer 10 steht ein kleines Technikgebäude).

Ich habe im ersten Turm mit der Hausnummer 6 gewohnt. Die Wohnungen liegen in den Stockwerken 5 bis 12 (darunter sind Garage, Shoppingmall und Büros), und es gibt in diesem einen Turm 128 Wohnungen. Ich habe auf Stiege 2 gewohnt, im 11. Stockwerk, und meine Wohnungstür war die erste in dieser Stiege und in diesem Stockwerk, daher hatte ich die Tür Nummer 1. Meine Postanschrift lautete also:

> Guglgasse 6/**2**/11/1
> 1110 Wien

Dass das Stockwerk Teil der Adresse ist, ist selten und amtlich gar nicht vorgesehen. Da haben sich die Architekten (oder wer immer für die Nummerierung verantwortlich war) vorher nicht mit den gesetzlichen Rahmenbedingungen auseinandergesetzt. Daher war ich offiziell an der Adresse »Guglgasse 6/2/1101« gemeldet, was immer wieder zu Verwirrungen bei Paketzustellern geführt hat.

Mich interessiert, wie die Adresse meiner ehemaligen Wohnung lauten würde, wenn die Nummern nach den in Deutschland geltenden Regeln vergeben würden. Insbesondere interessiert mich, wie man die Kategorie nennt, zu der die zweite Ziffer (also der Zweier) in meiner ehemaligen Postanschrift gehört.

Comment: In Norddeutschland ist eine Stiege eine Palette Bier :D

Comment: In Berlin findet man Zusätze wie "Vorderhaus" und "Hinterhaus". Ich weiß aber nicht, ob das in anderen Städten auch verbreitet ist oder nur der typischen Bauweise geschuldet ist. Daher nur als Kommentar.

Comment: In Deutschland gibt es das Haus, das hat eine Nummer zu haben (§126 BauGB). Mehr habe ich auch nicht gefunden. Somit ist der Rest m.E. nicht bindend, was die rechtliche Seite betrifft.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Aus Süddeutschland kenne ich Ähnliches, z.B. "Vordereingang" und "Rückgebäude". Es scheint keine festgelegten Begriffe hierfür zu geben; statt dessen wird oft ein beschreibender Begriff angewandt. Insgesamt vermute ich aber, dass diese Zusatzangaben eher der Orientierung dienen, während "formal" die Hausnummer an sich und der Name des Bewohners als ausreichend angesehen werden.

Comment: Aus der Frage : "bilden zusammen eine St**ei**ge [sic]. Die St**ei**ge [sic] selbst besteht dabei nur aus den einzelnen Treppen und den Plateaus". Ist die Schreibweise korrekt und *St**ei**ge* beschreibt etwas anderes als *St**ie**ge* -- oder handelt es sich um zwei Tippfehler?

Comment: Zur Prämisse: Ich halte es für möglich, dass mehrere Aufgänge in einem Wohnhaus in Deutschland selbst in Innenstädten aus architekturhistorischen Gründen deutlich seltener sind als z.B. in Wien, und sie in diesem Fall eher durch eine eigene Hausnummern oder eben mithilfe eines Buchstabenzusatzes unterschieden werden würden. Ein anderes Extrem wäre z.B. Rom, wo teilweise selbst Eingänge von Geschäften eine *eigene* 'Haus'nummer haben, also auch hier fehlt es an Stiegennummern.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Du hast recht, das sollte in allen Fälle »Stiege« heißen. Das war ein Tippfehler, der dreimal in meinem Text vorkam und den ich bis jetzt nicht bemerkt hatte. Ich habe diesen Fehler nun korrigiert. Danke für den Hinweis!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kurze Antwort: An sich gar nicht. Eine Adresse besteht in D im allgemeinen aus Postleitzahl, Ort, Strasse und Hausnummer.

Identifiziert diese Angabe die Wohnung nicht eindeutig (was sie i.Ü. rein rechtlich nicht unbedingt muss, sondern nur das Gebäude, in dem sich die Wohnung befindet), kann man mit Erweiterungen der Hausnummer arbeiten. An Gebäuden mit mehreren Eingängen wird z.B. öfters eine /1, /2 oder /3 an die Hausnummer angehängt, stehen auf einem Grundstück oder in einer Baulücke mehrere Gebäude, oder ist die dem Gebäude zuzuordnende Hausnummer nicht mehr frei, nimmt man auch gerne Kleinbuchstaben, um die Gebäude auseinanderzuhalten.

Früher war es bisweilen üblich, einer Postanschrift auch das *Stockwerk* mitzugeben. Das habe ich aber schon seit Jahrzehnten nicht mehr gesehen. In Ausnahmefällen gibt es in öffentlichen Formularen auch noch die Möglichkeit, eine *Wohnungsnummer* anzugeben. Das sieht man aber eher selten, solche Nummern sind nur in Gebäuden mit extrem vielen Wohnungen üblich).

Beispiele:

Typische Hausnummer für eins von mehreren Reihenhäusern auf einem gemeinsamen Grundstück.

> Mainstrasse 17d

Hausnummer für einen Wohnblock mit mehreren Eingängen (die angehängte "/2"  entspräche ungefähr deiner "Stiege")

> Rostocker Strasse 77/2

Es gibt in D m.W. weder eine *offiziell* noch eine *sprachlich* übergreifende Regel, die die spezifische Weise, wie eine "Hausnummer" auszusehen hat um genauer anzugeben, *wo* genau in einem möglicherweise großen Gebäude jemand wohnt, zentral regeln würde - Es gibt i.Ü. auch keine *generelle* Regel, wie eine Hausnummer *überhaupt* zu bilden ist (z.B. linke/rechte Strassenseite wechselnd, links auf- rechts absteigend o.Ä.). Ähnliches gilt, wenn entschieden werden muss, ob ein *Gebäude* oder eine *Parzelle* eine Nummer bekommen soll.

Jede Gemeide bildet sich ihre "Hausnummernregel" selbst und behält dies als Tradition üblicherweise auch bei. Mannheim z.B. "addressiert" ein Gebäude in der quadratischen Innenstadt als Koordinatenangabe ähnlich wie beim Schachspiel.

Hier noch ein Beispiel für die anzugebenden Bestandteile einer formell aufgenommenen Adresse. Das ist i.Ü eines der sehr wenigen amtlichen Formulare das ich kenne, das über Strasse und Hausnummer hinaus eine Angabe fordert:
[image]

Comment: +1, statt dem österreichischem *Stiege* heißt es in Deutschland *Aufgang*. Das Wort *Stiege* oder *-steig* wird in Deutschland nur für steile Wege am Hang verwendet.

Comment: Die Variante mit /1, etc. kenne ich gar nicht. War sie schon immer selten, ist sie seltener geworden oder ist sie nur regional üblich?

Comment: @Jan Ich habe die Variante mit /1 schon gesehen (Raum Frankfurt/Main), aber sie ist sehr selten.

Comment: Das mit den Kleinbuchstaben gibt es auch in Österreich, wenn z.B. eine Parzelle geteilt wird, und zwischen Holzweg 6 und Holzweg 8 ein neues Haus gebaut wird. Das bekommt dann Holzweg 6a. Davon handelt meine Frage aber nicht, denn das sind ja getrennte Häuser. Ich spreche von den »*Gebäuden mit extrem vielen Wohnungen*« wie du sie nennst. Also von Wohnhausanlagen mit 50 und mehr Wohnungen, wobei die Anlage auch mal 100 x 500 Meter groß ist, und von mir aus auch aus mehreren mehrstöckigen Pavilions besteht, aber alle auf einer Parzelle mit nur einer Hausnummer.

Comment: Die "17/1" - Methode kenne ich aus Stuttgart und sie wird hier wie gesagt bei "großen" Wohneinheiten verwendet.

Comment: Ich habe meine Antwort dahingehend ergänzt, dass es in D keine Regeln (weder sprachlich noch "amtlich") gibt, die eine Haus- oder Wohnungsnummer betreffen würden.

Comment: Wikipedia sagt in seinem Artikel über Hausnummern unter "Hausnummernergänzung", dass die "/1"-Nachstellung hauptsächlich in Württemberg verbreitet sei.

Comment: Ich kenne z.B. Einestraße 25 App 78 für die Wohnung Nummer 78 im Haus Einestraße 25. In welchem Stock oder an welcher Treppe Wohnung 78 dann liegt, ist normalerweise innerhalb des Hauses vom Haupteingang aus ausgeschildert (<- Wohnung 1-50, Wohnung 51-100 ->). Mitteldeutschland.

Answer (score 8):

Das direkte Äquivalent im deutschlanddeutschen Sprachgebrauch wäre wohl der *Aufgang.* Wie Tofro aber bereits gesagt hat, wird er in der Regel nicht wie in Österreich die Stiege als Bezeichnung verwendet. Stattdessen wird eine der folgenden Varianten verwendet:

- Gar keine nähere Beschreibung.

  Zum Beispiel wohnt ein Kollege in der Oststraße 35 (Straße und Hausnummer geändert). Geht man allerdings direkt zum Haus findet man allerdings nur einen Briefkasten mit seinem Namen, keine entsprechende Klingel; man muss zum Hinterhaus, wo ein zweiter, unbenannter Aufgang (deine »Stiege«) ist. Beide Häuser gemeinsam firmieren unter Oststraße 35.
- Zusätzlicher Kleinbuchstabe.

  Dies wird häufig bei Mietanlagen mit mehreren Aufgängen benützt. Dabei hat ein Aufgang die »Hauptnummer«, zum Beispiel Hauptstraße 38. Der zweite bekommt dann 38a, der dritte bekommt 38b – in der Regel. Es gibt auch Bauten, die nur aus Nummer, Nummer-b und Nummer-c bestehen; frag mich nicht, wieso. Und es muss sich dabei nicht um mehrere Aufgänge zu einem Gebäude handeln, es kann sich auch um physikalisch verschiedene Gebäude handeln, die auf einem Grundstück, einem Flurstück oder in einer Baulücke stehen.

  Im täglichen Gebrauch werden diese Buchstaben meist kleingeschrieben; manche Behörden oder Firmen bevorzugen Großschreibung.

  Wichtig ist, dass es zu einem Haus/Aufgang 51a auch *immer* ein äquivalentes 51 gibt – das ist anders als zum Beispiel in Finnland, wo entweder die Zahl alleine steht *oder* jeder Aufgang einen Buchstaben bekommt. (Dort hat man also entweder Asemantie 10 oder Asemantie 10A und 10B.)
- Direkte Bezeichnung der Wohnung (idR zusätzlich zu einer Kleinbuchstabenbezeichnung, wo nötig).

  Dies ist häufig bei sehr großen Anlagen mit sehr kleinen Wohneinheiten – zum Beispiel Studentenwohnheimen – anzutreffen. Dort kann dann die Adresse zum Beispiel auf Helmstedter Straße 25, Appartment 3141 lauten. (Adresse erfunden)

Meistens dient die Adresse in erster Linie dazu, der Post eindeutig den Weg zu weisen, d.h. zu einer bestimmten Adresse mit Hausnummer, ggf. Buchstaben findet sich in der Regel ein Briefkasten oder eine Briefkastensammlung (bei mehreren Wohnungen). Wenn, wie im ersten Beispiel, alle Briefkasten am Vorderhaus angebracht sind, kann der Zusatz »Hinterhaus« oder »-a« entfallen, weil die Post ihn nicht braucht.

Wie deine Beispieladresse genau lauten würde, kann man nicht exakt vorhersagen, ich würde aber die Variante »Guglgasse 6a« für die wahrscheinlichste Variante halten (zweiter Aufgang = in der Regel der a-Buchstabe hinter der Grundzahl).

Comment: Die Regel, dass es zu einem Haus mit der Hausnummer 320a auch *immer* ein Haus mit 320 geben müsse, mag für manche Gemeinden gelten. Hier in Stuttgart gilt sie nicht. Es gibt Hausnummern, wo dies gilt und welche, wo das nicht der Fall ist. Werden auf ein Grundstück, dem ursprünglich die Nummer x zugeordnet wurde, gleichzeitig 4 Reihenhäuser gebaut, bekommen diese die Nummern xa, xb, xc, xd. Wird zu einem existierenden Haus mit der Nummer x ein weiteres gebaut, behält das erste Haus die alte Nummer, das neue bekommt ein "a" angehängt.

Comment: In größeren Mietshäusern in Berlin heißen die (Neben)Eingänge eines Hauses immer Aufgänge, oft durch römische Ziffern untergliedert. Meistens gibt es ein Haupttor, -zugang und dann die weiteren Aufgänge.

Comment: Für Pakete und Einschreiben braucht die Post auch bei einem Briefkasten am Haupteingang eine genauere Bezeichnung, aber +1 für Aufgang.

Comment: @userunknown Mich haben Pakete bisher immer mit reiner Briefkastenangabe erreicht. (Gut, man muss auch nur an der entsprechenden Tür Hausnummer-a die Klingel suchen; das ist niedrigschwellig.)

Comment: Wenn in einem Gebäudekomplex viele Aufgänge sind, dann ist es für Lieferanten, Pizzabringedienste, Paketzusteller, Taxifahrer oder Notärzte eine große Vereinfachung, wenn sie nur am richtigen Aufgang die Klingeln absuchen müssen.

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, dafür haben viele Lieferdienste ein Zusatzfeld für »genauere Angaben zur Adresse (zum Beispiel *Hinterhaus)«*

Comment: Statt Aufgang gegebenenfalls auch Eingang ("Eingang Hinterhaus" oder "Eingang Nord"/"Nordeingang" - wobei ich letzteres eher mit Gewerbeimmobilien/Bürohäusern assoziiere)

Answer (score 8):

In Berlin musste ich bei der Anmeldung meiner Wohnung angeben, ob ich im Vorder-, Hinter- oder Gartenhaus wohne, und in welchem Stockwerk. Diese Angaben wurden im Formular unter "Zusätze" aufgezählt.

[image: Formular: Anmeldung bei der Meldebehörde]

Wenn ich nun Post von der Stadt Berlin bekomme steht bei der Adresse auf dem Brief nun auch immer all diese Angaben dabei, z.B.:

> Erika Mustermann
>
> Müllerstraße 10
>
> Hinterhaus, 2. Stock
>
> 10101 Berlin

Comment: Auch Seitenflügel oder SF ist ein gängiger Zusatz. Den Gebrauch Zusätze wie VH, HH oder SF in der Postadresse zu verwenden habe ich allerdings nur in Berlin gesehen. Ich wohne in einem Berliner Seitenflügel und es kommt immer wieder vor, dass Post ohne SF-Angabe mit Vermerk "Empfänger unbekannt" an den Absender zurückgeht.

Comment: @jarnbjo, bei uns kommen Briefe auch ohne Zusatz in der Adresse an, aber bei Paketen wird geklingelt und gefragt, wohin sie die Pakete bringen sollen (oder sie geben sie einfach bei den Nachbarn im 1. Stock im Vorderhaus an)

Comment: Statt HH auch Quergebäude. Für Pakete etwa als Kürzel "2q3r" 2. Quergebäude, 3. Stock, rechts.

Comment: @userunknown, das habe ich so noch nie gehört und würde ich auch nicht spontan verstehen.

Answer (score 3):

In Berlin gibt es den Begriff "Aufgang", der verschiedene Eingänge bzw. Treppenhäuser bezeichnet. Auch in der Postanschrift wird dann zwischen Aufgang I und Aufgang II oder Aufgang A oder B unterschieden. So zum Beispiel hier: https://service.berlin.de/standort/122243/